# Speed Date or Dating Conversation Dataset / Corpora

Tags: dataset

I'm working on an LSTM model that uses dating conversation dataset. Any suggestion as to where I can get such data? Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that you are never going to come across this, most of this data is closely guarded. It's no secret that dating sites like OK Cupid use data science on their app, so I think that most of these sites aren't quick to make their data public.

Answer (score -1):

SpeedDate Corpus collected by the third author, and described in [Jurafsky et al. (2009)](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/emnlp09.pdf)